# Lion's Display Calibrator Assistant is missing calibration images

Tags: macos, display

I'm trying to use the Display Calibrator Assistant in OS X Lion (10.7.4) with my Samsung 2494HM HDMI monitor, but the assistant appears to be missing some reference calibration images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhyrV.png

However, the slider images that appear later in the calibration process (with a solid grey apple logo embedded in an array of grey horizontal stripes) do display properly.

Any idea why these brightness calibration images are missing on my system, and how to resolve it?

Comment: What happens if you turn on Expert mode from the Introduction (first step)?